# Equivalent implementation of Committed, OnAfterInstall, OnBeforeUninstall, OnBeforeInstall in Wix custom action

Tags: c#, wix, .net-3.5, setup-project

I am migrating my old Windows setup project to wix installer.
On my old InstallerClass, I have four events Committed, OnAfterInstall, OnBeforeUninstall,  OnBeforeInstall

While from Wix custom action I found [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/custom.html),
I think it has provisioning of only After and Before.

How can I map my old Installer class code into four separate custom actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Committed is a WiX Execute=Commit custom action.

All the others have names that seem to offer choices but they do not really. There is no "OnBeforeInstall" event - this is something internal to Visual Studio, it's a custom action that's called before the other managed code custom actions are called. It is pointless in WiX with no equivalent.  In any case it is NOT before the install. It is the same thing as calling a WiX deferred custom action after the StartServices action.

The same is true for OnAfterInstall. It is the same as WiX deferred custom action called after StartServices, and after any of your other custom actions.

OnBeforeUninstall is also a Visual Studio oddity that it the same as calling a deferred custom action before StopServices.

All Visual Studio custom actions are in the InstallExecuteSequence and have impersonate=no.

The other thing that Visual Studio hides is that they are internally conditioned on components being installed and uninstalled (most of the time) so you'll need to understand conditions as well as immediate/deferred/impersonated that are hidden from you by Visual Studio.

Once you've generated an MSI file with Visual Studio you can use Orca (from Windows SDK/Kit) to open the MSI file and look at the InstallExecuteSequence table, click on sequence to order in their actual order. Along with the standard actions you'll see your custom actions and when they are called, and their type and their conditions. They are defined in the CustomAction table.

Having said all that, they won't work because the other thing Visual Studio hides is the C++ Dll infrastructure that provides that odd calling environment. Managed code custom actions in WiX are not like VS managed code custom actions, so you'll need to migrate the code to the WiX model. Examples here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511653/Using-WIX-with-Managed-Custom-Action

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jschaffe/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters/

Comment: Thanks PhilDW. I am following the same links.